# HTML5 banner, rich media sample

Tags: google-ads-api, double-click, banner-ads, double-click-advertising, rich-media

I want to find a sample of rich media with added Enabler to look how should I do it properly. As soon as I add Enabler script to my head> tag, will it gather all the metrics that google anlytics need? Or should I add other modules or call some methods?

Can you please send me a sample of rich media banner (or whatever) where I can see proper work with studio HTML5 SDK and Enabler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download samples from http://www.richmediagallery.com/create/templates